# How to parse this text file in java?

Tags: java, file, parsing, date, pattern-matching

I have to parse a txt file like this in java :

```
01/01/2008 00:00      15581      15647      15646      15630      15641      15649
01/01/2008 01:00      15630      15628      15633      15617      15656      15680
01/01/2008 02:00      15622      15656      15668      15644      15681      15633
01/01/2008 03:00      15631      15665      15684      15648      15640      15634
01/01/2008 04:00      15615      15638      15637      15650      15646      15665
01/01/2008 05:00      15642      15651      15644      15640      15632      15638
01/01/2008 06:00      15633      15647      15632      15654      15635      15633
...
```

In each line: 
-the first column is the date (dd/mm/yyyy)
-the second is the hour (hh:mm)
-from the third to the 8th, it is some value every ten minutes (in exemple: 15581 is the value at 00:00, 15647 the value at 00:10, etc...)

I have to parse this in a two dimensiosn table to draw a chart.

And I don't know how to do this.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: which information do you wish to parse and store in your 2-D array?

Comment: The complete date (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm) and its associate value.
In Exemple : [[01/01/2008 00:00 , 15581] , [01/01/2008 00:10 , 15647] , ...]

Comment: There are many examples on the web.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I would use @FlrDataType, meaning fixed length record, on an object class. For example

```
@FlrDataType
public class MyRecord {

   @FlrField(pos = 1, length = 10)
   String date;

   @FlrField(pos = 12, length = 5)
   String time;

   @FlrField(pos = 25, length = 5) //not sure on position 25, cant count your spaces
   String value1;

   //etc + getters/setters
}
```

and then in your main file you use Deserializer to create the object like this

```
Deserializer deserialMyRecord = FlrIOFactory.createFactory(MyRecord.class).createDeserializer();
```

and then use a StringReader to read in your file

```
String rec = myFile.readLine();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(rec);
deserialMyRecord.open(reader);
while(deserialMyRecord.hasNext()) {
   MyRecord myRecord = deserialMyRecord.next();
}
```

edit* sorry the library is jsefa

```
org.jsefa.flr.annotation
```

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: It seems great. I don't have a lot of time right now, but I will try it soon. I keep U in touch.